# Display first date in MATLAB plot

Tags: matlab, date, plot

I want to display the very first date in below figure which is the 1.1.1997

Thats my syntax

```
plot(MATLABDate(1:end-2),sumbeta)
datetick('x','mm/yyyy','keeplimits')
```

Haven't found how to do...

[image]

Comment: Are you saying you want the left edge of your axis to be 1.1.1997?

Comment: @IanRiley Yes, exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [xlim](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlim.html) function to set x-axis limits. If you only want to modify the lower limit, you can directly modify the value in the current x-axis:

```
>> hAx = gca;
>> hAx.XLim(1) = datenum('1/1/1997');
```